# Android AudioRecord read method: Can it ever read more data than has been recorded?

Tags: android, audiorecord

I am having alot of issues with the android AudioRecord class. I have always been confused with how the read method within AudioRecord works, hopefully someone can answer...

Consider this scenario;

1. I have created a new AudioRecord object with a sampleRateInHz value of 44100hz
2. I then call the startRecording() method and the device starts recording input from the microphone.
3. Exactly 500ms (or 22050 samples) later I call the read method and try to read 44100 samples into a new array with a length of 44100.

Since the AudioRecord object has only been recording for 500ms (or 22050 samples) and I am trying to read the last 44100 samples, what will happen? My possible thoughts are;

- The read method will sleep for 500ms until there is sufficient data available and then read all of the 44100 recorded samples, or
- The read method will read what is in the AudioRecord buffer (within the AudioRecord object) regardless of how much data has been recorded to it. So in this case, the first 22050 samples will contain data recorded from the microphone and the subsequent 22050 samples will contain zeros as the read function is accessing an area of the buffer that has not been written to yet.

I have tried tirelessly to test this with my android device, but it is really not an easy thing to test. It will take a greater mind than I to answer...Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also found this unclear, as the Android documentation doesn't really say.  However there are several answers on SO in which people confirm that the **first** of your two options are true - the method blocks until enough data is available.  [Have a look at the second answer to this question for a rather detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569421/problem-of-read-method-in-audiorecord-class).